# mocha tests not found: "0 passing"

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js

I dont know why the test runner wont detect my tests.

```
npm test

myproject@1.0.0 test C:\Users\sjsui\Desktop\git_workshop\myproject
mocha ./built/source

  0 passing (4ms)

PS C:\Users\sjsui\Desktop\git_workshop\myproject>
```

I know that `test` is the default folder that mocha searches for so that is how I structured my project.

```
built
\--source
    \--test
        \--test.js
```

**here is my test.js file**

```
describe("consumer tests", function()
{
    it("runs bad request tests", (done) => {
        let tests = new badrequesttests()
        iteratebadtests(tests, done)

    })


    it("normal consumer tests", (done) => {
        let tests = new normaltests()
        iteratenormaltests(tests, done)
    })

    it("abnormal consumer tests", (done) => {
        let tests = new unauthorizedtests()
        iterateunauthorizedtests(tests, done)
    })
})
```

**npm scripts section in package.json**

```
  "scripts": {

      "test": "mocha ./built/source"

  },
```

as a side note, break points wont hit inside the test (visual studio code debug task -> mocha)

Comment: what is inside `iteratenormaltests` and others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your test scripts are not detected y mocha because by default mocha does not scan sub-directories and your tests are inside a subdirectory of path you are passing at the time of invking mocha. There are two ways to resolve this.

1. Provide the path of test folder to mocha as below

   ```
   mocha ./built/source/test
   ```
2. Trigger mocha tests with recursive flag. Using this flag mocha will scan the subdirectories of the path you provide

   ```
   mocha ./built/source --recursive
   ```

I think this should solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the directory to search for your test files like below:

```
mocha -- ./built/source/**/*.test.js
```

This will check for all test files ending with `.test.js` in their file name in any directory within the `source` directory.

```
mocha -- ./built/source/*.test.js
```

That will check for test files within the `source` directory.